# Setting iCloud files to online-only

Tags: icloud, storage

I'm looking for the iCloud equivalent of setting files & folders to online-only in the way that you can with MS OneDrive and Dropbox (see screengrab at the bottom).

This is on a colleagues computer that I'm trying to help with, so I'm unable to take a screenshot of how it looks.

When I right-click on her files / folders, I see no option that relates to freeing up space on their harddrive and storing online.

I can however, see a grey cloud icon next to (most of) them.

When right-clicking on the files, they appear to be taking up around 10GB of space. But I'm looking to free this up

[image]

Comment: The linked answer doesn't work for me

Comment: iCloud isn't really meant for what people try to make it do, it's just a not-very-reliable sync solution.   You should use a service that actually does what you want.